# Adding new attribute flags to an existing attribute in Android XML

Tags: android, android-xml

When using the XML to style your fonts, you can use either of these typeface flags on the `android:textStyle` attribute: `bold`, `italic`, `normal`.

I'm mapping this attribute with my custom font, so `bold` corresponds with my bold font, etc. Now  for example I have a semi-bold style that I also want to use with this attribute, but currently the default `textStyle` attribute can only accept those 3 values. Is there any way I could make a new custom flag under that attribute? For example I want to be able to do this `android:textStyle="semibold"`.

I can use other unused flag in place for the style I want to use but it's very unintuitive to write `android:textStyle="italic"` and have it show a semi-bold font.

Comment: You can use own attributes

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski yes I can do that, but I want to use the existing one if possible.